# Can I reduce a non semi decidable and undecidable language to a semi decidable and undecidable langauge? many-one reduction

Tags: computability, reductions, undecidability, halting-problem, semi-decidability

Let's say a Language ***L*** is **NON-semi decidable** and **undecidable**. Let's also take the Halting problem ***H***, which is a **semi decidable** and **undecidable** language.

Is it possible to reduce ***L*** to ***H***  in a **many-one reduction**? I know that both are undecidable languages, and we can reduce an **undecidable** language to another **undecidable** language, but ***L*** being **NON-semi-decidable** and ***H*** being **semi decidable** kinda gives me the idea that these languages are not compatible, and a reduction is not possible. (Why? Well, I think, we are reducing a "harder" language to an "easier" one. It should be the other way around).

If a reduction was possible, are we reducing to just show the undecidability part of both languages but ignoring the (non) semi-decidable part?

Extra question: Would the other way around be possible? **H** reduced to **L**?

I think **yes**. Well both undecidable, compatible, this part is clear to me. But now we are reducing a semi-decidable language to a non semi-decidable language,which should be "harder". In theory in the lecture when A<B, what we learned is that on the left side of the reduction (A) is max as "hard"  as the right side of the reduction (B).

--Edit--

Specified in the title **many-one Reduction**. As Nathaniel pointed out, there are 2 types of reduction (which I wasn´t aware of) and what I needed in this question was the **many-one Reduction**.

Comment: For you extra question: you are right, this is possible, even with many-one reductions: this is because there are undecidable problem which are strictly harder than semi-decidable problems. For instance you can take $L$ to be the set of all (encodings of) deterministic Turing machines that halt on **every** input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the reduction.

Using a [Turing reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction), it is possible. For example, any problem $A$ is Turing-reducible to its complement $\overline{A}$, by puting a negation on an answer given by an algorithm solving $\overline{A}$. If $\overline{A}$ is semi-decidable but undecidable, then $A$ is not semi-decidable (otherwise it would be decidable). If you consider $\overline{A}$ to be the halting problem, then you have your answer.

Note that it is not always possible that such a reduction exists.

Using a [many-one reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction), it is not possible, because if $A\leqslant_m B$ and $A$ is not semi-decidable, then $B$ is not semi-decidable, otherwise, you could, for an instance $x$ of $A$, compute $y = f(x)$ using the reduction, and then $x\in A$ if and only if $y \in B$, and you could use the algorithm that solves $B$ partially to solve $A$ partially.

Comment: thnx for the answer.  I will specify it that this is a many-one reduction. In our lecture this is not even mentioned, but after seeing some examples i´m sure my case was about many-one reduction (german Uni system here)